# Error ImportError: No module named 'bpy'

Tags: python, game-engine

I am getting error:

> ImportError: No module named 'bpy' in Blender console.

I am importing bpy module inside Blender console but still getting the error. After long googling I found that no one is getting the same error inside Blender.

Using Blender 2.7 and python 3.4.

My code:

```
import sys   
import bpy     
sys.path.append("C:\Python34\Lib\site-packages")    
import serial    
import GameLogic    
contr = GameLogic.getCurrentController()    
own = contr.owner    
dane=open('dane.txt', 'rb')    
x=dane.read()    
dane.close()    
y = int(x)    
print ("y=", y)    

bpy.ops.transform.rotate(value=(y), axis=(0.0, 0.0, 0.0), constraint_axis=(False, False, False), constraint_orientation='', mirror=False, proportional='DISABLED', proportional_edit_falloff='SMOOTH', proportional_size=1.0, snap=False, snap_target='CLOSEST', snap_point=(0.0, 0.0, 0.0), snap_align=False, snap_normal=(0.0, 0.0, 0.0), release_confirm=False)
```

Output at Blender console:

```
ImportError: No module named 'bpy'  
Python script error - object 'Cube', controller 'Python':  
Traceback (most recent call last):  
File "qqq.py", line 2, in <module>  
ImportError: No module named 'bpy'
```

Comment: There's at least one additional problem: the backslashes in the filepath are not escaped, you can fix this by adding an `r` in front of the starting quotation mark - `sys.path.append(r"...")`

Comment: Thanks dear friend for your reply. This problem persists only in Standalone Player, not in embedded player. But I need the standalone player. :(

Have any solution dear ?

Answer (score 3):

The blenderplayer doesn't include `bpy`

Comment: Do you mean to say that there is no way to include `bpy` in Standalone Player?
And when we export the game runtime as an .exe, in which player the game is played(Embedded or Standalone)?

Comment: correct. unless you modify the player code in C/C++ to include it (not trivial)

Comment: What is the procedure to include that `bpy` in C/C++? Because I need to publish the game for end-users.

Please share any method to include `bpy` in exported runtime version. Any method will help.

Comment: By not trivial I mean you can't do it unless you spend some hours in the code - this needs a developer to look into it, and infact its intentionally setup this way. since bpy is for blender -the application. You would be better off to just run Blender application fullscreen I expect.